# Declaring a pointer syntax in a function

Tags: c

Are both pointer statements the same?

```
void reverse(const char * const sPtr){


}
```

and

```
void reverse(const char const *sPtr){


}
```

Comment: @Dan Or not. Using `typedef` for object pointer types is discouraged.

Comment: @ouah: who discourages that, and why would you care what's discouraged by somebody who apparently has no clue what he's talking about?

Comment: @ouah: So your basic position is that Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie (to give just a couple of obvious examples) never had "a clue in C". Somehow I'm reminded of the proud mother watching the parade saying: "Look, look, everybody in the whole band except my Johny is out of step!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

`const char const *sPtr` is equivalent to
`const char *sPtr`.

`const char *sPtr` say parameter `sPtr` is a pointer to a `const char`.

`const char * const sPtr` is a `const` pointer to a `const char`.

Note that this is equivalent in C99 and C11:

> (C99, 6.7.3p4) "If the same qualifier appears more than once in the same specifier-qualifier-list, either directly or via one or more typedefs, the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once."

but not in C89 where `const char const *sPtr` is a constraint violation:

> (C90, 6.5.3) "The same type qualifier shall not appear more than once in the same specifier list or qualifier list, either directly or via one or more typedefs."

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve?

If you want a const pointer you have to put `const` after the `*`

```
int * const a;
```

If you want a pointer to const you have to put the `const` before the `*`

```
const int *a;
```

Comment: Going to take string and just reverse it with a printf statement.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The first is a `const` pointer to `const char`.

The second is a pointer to a `const char`.

`const` binds to left, or to right is there is nothing on the left.